# Is Composer for server or local use?

Tags: php, composer-php

Is [Composer](http://getcomposer.org) designed to be installed on a web server **or** on a local computer?

Comment: I think it makes more sense to have it on a dev machine.  That way, you can test updates to the packages before pushing them to the live server.

Comment: @KevinM1 Makes sense. That's how they demo it in http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QOldVDVYnAE

Answer (score 7):

It is designed for both.

You can use it in development (you will use `composer update` a lot then) and you can use it in production (you will install your dependencies with `composer install` then).

In development phrase, you define with which dependencies your project works. And in production, you make sure these dependencies are installed.